# Does Happy Street sync between Android and iOS?

Tags: ios, android, happy-street

I've got an iPad and an Android phone. If I download Happy Street on both will I be able to play the same game, or will it be two different streets?

Comment: Do you have to log in to play? If you don't, then almost certainly not.

Comment: @fredley you can log in via facebook. But cross-platform data sharing is spotty in general. I haven't tried Happy Street but I could try that tonight if no one else knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played the game for some time and I've never seen any ability to sync your game with the cloud.  I believe your street is tied to your device identity, so GameCenter for iOS and GooglePlay for Android - this does not appear to be something that you can change in game.  You ***do*** have the ability to log into Facebook, but it appears to only be used for cross platform friending, resource sharing, and park visits.  As such, with your two devices you could definitely "friend yourself" via Facebook and share items back and forth (though you might need an extra Facebook account to do so).  Given the wait times for some components and the colored crystals which are unique for each street, that might be very beneficial.